# Separate java object creation in each iteration

Tags: java, arrays

```
public class Test{

    public void setMembersValues(List list){

        List<Member>  memberList = new ArrayList<Member>();

        for(Object o : list){

            String[] str = o.split("\n");

            if(str.equalsIgnoreCase("<member>")){

                /**I want to create separate member objects for each 
                   list iterration.But member refers same object.**/

                Member member = new Member();

                for(int i =0; i<str.length;i++){

                    if(str[i].equalsIgnoreCase("<member/>")){
                        memberList.add(member);
                        break;
                    }else{
                        if(str[i].equalsIgnoreCase("name"))
                            member.setName(str[i].split("//")[1]);
                    }else if(str[i].equalsIgnoreCase("Address")){
                        member.setAddress(str[i].split("//")[1]);
                    }
                }

            }

        }
    }
}
```

There are two lists here, but only one member object is created. I want to create separate member objects for each iteration and add it to memberList.

How can I do it, please?

Comment: you know there are tools to unserialize xml? Can you post the xml input?

Comment: Actually , I am not using XML tool. I just break down the string this way.

Answer (score 3):

> I want to create separate member objects for each iteration and add it to memberList.

You need to create a new object for each time you go around the inner loop.  You are creating a single `Member` outside of the loop and adding it to the list multiple times.

Comment: Actually , I want to create a separate object for first for loop. In this list, list size is 2. I need to add member details two objects.

Answer (score 1):

You can move your Member instantiation inside the for loop:

```
        for(int i =0; i<str.length;i++){
            if(str[i].equalsIgnoreCase("<member/>")){
                memberList.add(member);
                Member member = new Member();
                break;
```

[Edited]

Comment: Actually , I want to create a separate object for first for loop. In this list, list size is 2. I need to add member details two objects.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.  I think you need to create a new Member right after adding  the previous one.